# Flutter send notfication without server

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications from app to app without any server and rest api with Flutter. How can I do this?

I want to send notifaction in flutter but there is no any server. And I want to send notification from website created by flutter and mobile application

Comment: Sending messages through FCM API can only be securely done from a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or cloud functions). If you do this from a non-trusted environment, the users may send any message they want to any of your users - which is a security risk. This has been covered extensively in the past, so rather than repeating it in an answer here, I've linked some previous ones.